# How to Increase bass/treble audio levels for avi files when re-encoding

Tags: avi

Virtualdub does not do this fast as far as I can see.

Can someone give me an awesome pointer since I have some old series (more than a 100 individual avi files) with a soundtrack that can definitely do with quite a bit of bass or graphic equalizer adjustment on the soundtrack. Since it is series of individual files, batch processing is a must.

Comment: Do you want to save the changes to the avi files, or just adjust the audio levels while they are playing?

Comment: I want to save the changes to the avi files - so a standard change applied to a series of files.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked for EQ or audio manipulation plugins for VirtualDub?

It seems that while VirtualDub by default doesn't support audio plugins, there is a fork hosted at http://www.virtualdub.net that does and there is apparently a filterpack there that you may want to look into. I cannot explore this right now as it's blocked on my work computer.

Comment: Look promising - this will take a while (Thanks for the info)

Comment: I had a look, but it does not seem to do what I want.